# Result consisted of more than one row error mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the next available id through a stored procedure but so far I cant make this to work. This is my stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `devt`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `updateid`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `updateid`(IN `tran_id` VARCHAR(15), IN `typ` VARCHAR(15), OUT `lid` VARCHAR(15))
BEGIN
DECLARE id VARCHAR(15);
SET id =  '';
SELECT TranID FROM journal WHERE TranID = tranid INTO id;
read_loop: LOOP
            SELECT TranID FROM journal WHERE TranID = id INTO id;
    IF id = tran_id THEN
        UPDATE journaltype SET journaltype.NextRefNbr = journaltype.NextRefNbr + 1 WHERE journaltype.JournalType = typ;
        SELECT journaltype.NextRefNbr FROM journaltype WHERE journaltype.JournalType = typ INTO id;
        ITERATE read_loop;
    ELSE
        SET lid= id;
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
END LOOP;
END$$

DELIMITER ;**strong text**
```

when i run the query CALL updateid('17000001','GJ', @test) i get an error Result consisted of more than one row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error probably means that you either have multiple entries with the same `TranID` in table `journal` or multiple entries with the same `JournalType`  in table `journaltype`.

When using the `SELECT...INTO...` syntax you have to be sure that the returned resultset will *not* consist of more than one rows.

Comment: Im pretty sure that the value that will be retrieved is just a single entry. the column tranid is a unique key. same goes with the type

Comment: Have you tried to run the `SELECT` statements "manually" (and without the `INTO`-part) and see what is returned ?

Comment: yup. it returned a single value.

Comment: @John Sorry, I tried everything I could think of and yet it works as intended when there are no duplicates in `journal.TranID` and `journaltype.JournalType` and throws a "Result consisted of more than one row" error when there are multiple entries with the same value on one of these fields. You could try adding `LIMIT 1` (before `INTO`) to all your `SELECT` queries and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: it works now. I forgot to replace SELECT TranID FROM journal WHERE TranID = tranid INTO id; with SELECT TranID FROM journal WHERE TranID = tran_id INTO id; I also did some modifications on the code

Answer (score 0):

ONE of your **SELECT** statement is returning more than one row you need to be more clear on results for example

Instead of using this :

```
SELECT journaltype.NextRefNbr FROM journaltype WHERE journaltype.JournalType = typ INTO id;
```

Use this :

```
SELECT journaltype.NextRefNbr FROM journaltype WHERE journaltype.JournalType = typ INTO id LIMIT 1;
```

this will resolve your error!.
Try to use in every SELECT statement if it is using no indexed column in WHERE clause